# Substring finder efficiency

Tags: java

I've been going over some online Java tests after, ill be honest, an incredibly long time away from coding, to try and get a grip on the language again. Anywho, one questions was to make a substring finding method without using "Java APIs such as indexOf, substring or contains".

So I came up with this.

```
public class test{

int countThis;
String needle = "needle";
String haystack = "haystack";
String le = "le";
String hay = "hay";

char[] charA, charB, charC, charD;

public static void main(String args[]){
  test test = new test();
  test.go();
}

public void go(){
  charA = haystack.toCharArray();
  charB = needle.toCharArray();
  charC = le.toCharArray();
  charD = hay.toCharArray();

  boolean testThis = recursion(charA, needle, 0, countThis);
  boolean testThis1 = recursion(charB, le, 0, countThis);
  boolean testThis2 = recursion(charD, hay, 0, countThis);
  boolean testThis3 = recursion(charB, hay, 0, countThis);
  boolean testThis4 = recursion("liiijdiijy".toCharArray(), "iijy", 0, countThis);
  boolean testThis5 = recursion("liiijdiijy".toCharArray(), "needle", 0, countThis);
  boolean testThis6 = recursion("nyeyeydylye".toCharArray(), "needle", 0, countThis);

  System.out.println(testThis);
  System.out.println(testThis1);
  System.out.println(testThis2);
  System.out.println(testThis3);
  System.out.println(testThis4);
  System.out.println(testThis5);
  System.out.println(testThis6);
}

public boolean recursion(char[] aA, String bB, int i, int count){
  if(i > aA.length-1) return false;
  if(aA[i] == bB.charAt(count))
    count++;
  else
    count = 0;
  return (count == bB.length()) ? true : recursion(aA, bB, i+=1, count);
}
}
```

Please excuse the naming, but how efficient is this, specifically the recursive method? I'm not sure on how the `toCharArray()` will affect it. Besides that, any ways to improve it? I was thinking a regex would do it SO much better but I'm useless with them at the moment.

Comment: It's not as efficient as it should be: toCharArray() creates a full copy of the internal char array, and recursion is less efficient than an iterative solution. But the main problem is that it will explode with a StackOverflowError as soon as your string becomes a bit large. You could use a regex, but if you authorize yourself to use regexes, why would you forbid yourself to use the appropriate method: contains()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a regex like this:

```
^.*%SUBSTRING%.*$
```

for example, if you want to check whether "o, W" is included in "Hello, World!":

```
"Hello, World!".matches("^.*" + Pattern.quote("o, W") + ".*$")
```

this returns true.

You can use a method like this:

```
private static boolean isSubString(final String string, final String subString) {
    return string.matches("^.*" + Pattern.quote(subString) + ".*$");
}
```